# Audio not playing on Android (Kitkat 4.4.2 on LG G Pro 2 D838) via HTTPS

Tags: tls, mobile, android, chrome, audio

I am having issues playing an audio file on the chrome browser!

This [audio file](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/9f/Sample_of_%22Another_Day_in_Paradise%22.ogg) plays on the chrome browser on my mobile LG G Pro-2(D838) running Kitkat 4.4.2 without any issues. 
But when i uploaded this same file to our server and tried to open it on chrome browser, it does not play. Here is the [link](https://frontend.lifetape.com/download/p_ml/test/Sample_of_Another_Day_in_Paradise.ogg) to the file at our server.

Now the server is configured for HTTPS access only. When I tried playing the file after enabling HTTP access, the audio played.
Also, the images and other content on our server is accessible on the same mobile device via HTTPS. The audio file also plays on other mobile devices running same Android version(Google Nexus 4 running 4.4.2).

We are using certificate provided by StartSSL(free version).

Is there something wrong with the SSL certificate we are using? Or is it the problem with the device?

Comment: This is a Chrome support question, not an InfoSec question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how the audio playing is done on the device, but if an external application outside chrome is used for download the content, then the problem might be the use of [SNI (Server Name Indication)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). Some Android applications still have problems with SNI, especially if they where built with Apaches HTTP client library.

But, your site requires SNI. That is, if you access the site with SNI you get the right certificate for frontend.xxxx, but without SNI you get the certificate for app.xxxx which does not match the used host name and thus is invalid for the connection.

Comment: Thanks @Steffen. You pointed me in the right direction. That was the issue.